# LogCat android unity app crashes before splash screen can't find error

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, build

I don't really understand what I am looking at, I have read through this multiple times.

I tried removing my sd card and starting over. Android s9+ pie. unity builds. It has admob and external links in app.
The last 3 things I did different from this build(last build was perfect and installed to my phone)
I changed some assets colors, added admob ads, added music with ads inbetween songs, and i added a timer to the front page 'PLAY' button, I've gone back through each step and removed and have tried to build again but no luck..
PLEASE HELP.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z8hbNZKfmSbudyGyDyJGk68NPRymwZLk

please use google drive code link above!!!

```
C:\Users\tstw\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb logcat -s Unity 
ActivityManager PackageManager dalvikm DEBUG
--------- beginning of crash
 --------- beginning of main
10-08 03:27:24.463  3285  6180 D PackageManager: setEnabledSetting : userId = 
0 packageName = com.samsung.android.app.telephonyui cmp = 
com.samsung.android.app.telephonyui.netsettings.ui.NetSettingsActivity 
newState = 1 callingPackage = 1001/com.samsung.android.app.telephonyui
```

Comment: "CANT PASTE ANY MORE CODE" in log looks like there are not full log output. can you share full log here (maybe via pastebin or etc. if simple past cuting log) ?

Comment: hi thank you ! i have added a psatebin link!

Comment: hm... also looks like not full logs) can you remove `-s Unity 
ActivityManager PackageManager dalvikm DEBUG` and share full full log?) in any way, there are need to be stack traces - we can find errors there)

Comment: hi i removed the emailto: application openurl in playmaker button and it built just fine... ive been having a ton of issues with all of my external links..

Comment: so, problem solved?)

Comment: hi i added a new file please see attached link above!!

Comment: Mmm... Can't find "com.tsw.test" or any crashes in new logs... Are you sure that you had catched needed moment with app crash?

Comment: Also, there are logs with FirebaseCrash system... Are you used it or it not yours? If used - you also can find some crash reports there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I didnt learn how to use logcat properly until last night. My manifest and my grade templates were overriding my inputs. I manually fixed the issue it threw an APP ID invalid. Thank you for your help!